# Regular expression on Python to split string by symbol without deleting

Tags: python, regex, split

I am trying to write a function that does something like this:

```
>> foo("String. New sentence. And again.")
["String.", "New sentence.", "And again."]
```

I read the documentation on `regex` and wrote this code:

```
def foo(string):
    return re.split(r'([.!?])', string)
```

This function outputs keeps the punctuation, but separates it from the sentences:

```
["String", ".", "New sentence", ".", "And again", "."]
```

I want to have the 3 whole sentences separated.

How can I improve this function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include the characters before the ending delimiter, and try `re.findall`:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "String. New sentence. And again."
>>> re.findall(r'[^ ].*?[.!?]', s)
['String.', 'New sentence.', 'And again.']
```

The `[^ ]` means we're looking for something that doesn't start with a space. The `.*?` means any characters, not including the `[.!?]` that follows them.

Answer (score 0):

something like

```
import re
def foo(string):
    return re.findall(r'\s*([a-zA-Z0-9 -,\']+[\.!\?]+)\s*', string)
```

will return an array of "sentences". Modify the regex to accommodate the sorts of characters you might see.

eg.

```
string = "This isn't what I had in mind, but it will do. WHAT!!? OK, OK stop typing already."
re.findall(r'\s*([a-zA-Z0-9 -,\']+[\.!\?]+)\s*', string)
["This isn't what I had in mind, but it will do.", 'WHAT!!?', 'OK, OK stop typing already.']
```